# Cordova - Uploading to Google App Engine signedUrl - Content-MD5 not matching

Tags: php, cordova, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Having a bit of an issue; I am trying to upload to a PUT signed url - but any time I add in 'content-md5' to my upload header GCS responds with

```
<Message>The MD5 you specified in Content-MD5 or x-goog-hash was invalid.</Message>
<Details>Invalid MD5 value: ZWFmMjRlNmE0OTExMjRhMTllYmYxYzU2ODliOWIyZGE=</Details>
```

I can confirm that `eaf24e6a491124a19ebf1c5689b9b2da` is the correct MD5, and I am providing it in base64 form. When I upload the file manually to my bucket and check the MD5 content it matches with `eaf24e6a491124a19ebf1c5689b9b2da`.

My signed URL is being made with

```php
$url = $object->signedUrl(
    new \DateTime("60 min"),
    [
        "method" => "PUT",
        'version' => 'v4',
        "contentType" => "application/octet-stream"
        "contentMd5" => base64_encode($md5)
    ]
);
```

On the Cordova side I am using the FileTransfer plugin

```js
    var uploadFileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";
    options.httpMethod = "PUT";
    options.fileName = "my_file.zip";
    options.mimeType = "application/octet-stream";
    options.headers = {
        "content-md5": btoa(fileMd5),
        'content-type': 'application/octet-stream'
    }


    uploadFileTransfer.upload(file, url, success, fail, options);
```

If I remove `content-md5`, the upload works. Any help is greatly appreciated here, thanks.

Comment: In order to discard any issue with gcp, could you try to upload a file using the [XML API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object)? Also, did you encoded the Uri as stated in the official docs of [Cordova](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#uploading-an-object)?